# Creating a hash of an array of 3 numbers with the following structure?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Consider the following array:

0 1 0

1 1 1

2 2 0

3 3 1

4 5 1

I'm trying to find the fastest way to hash the array such that other permutations of the 3rd column will give the same hash.

For example the following should get the same hash as the one above:

0 1 1

1 1 0

2 2 1

3 3 0

4 5 0

The first column will always be starting at 0 and increasing, an index.
The second can be essentially any value.
The third column represents categories. As long as the set of categories, contains the same index, value pairs. The hash should be the same.

E.g. from the first example:

Category 1: [1, 1] [3, 3] [4, 5]

Category 0: [0, 1] [2, 2]

E.g. from the second example:

Category 1: [0, 1] [2, 2]

Category 0: [1, 1] [3, 3] [4, 5]

Because the set of categories are the same, they should produce the same hash.

I'm trying to write a hashcode() function that essentially does this in the fastest way as runtime is a major concern.

I'm currently just creating a stack for each category by adding the integers of the pairs in order one by one. Then adding the stack to a set, and getting the hashcode of the set.

E.g. Stack1 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5]

E.g. Stack0 = [0, 1, 2, 2]

Them I add the stacks to a set and get that hashcode.

Comment: Please show some code, or provide a better description of the input and expected output. As described, I don't understand the need for an intermediate stack. Why you can't just add things directly to the hash table is a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the sum of the 3rd column part of your hash-value. The sum is the same for all permutations (also product or xor would work)

Or all of them sum, xor and product that reduces the number of collisions for the 3rd column where the columns are not a permutation.

```
a f k    
b g l   
c h m 
d i n
e j o
```

a hashCode could be 
abcdefghijxyz
where:

```
x=k+l+m+n+o  
y=k*l*m*n*o   
z=k^l^m^n^o
```